# Add my own class file in ASP.NET MVC, and it couldn't be referenced?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am currently stuck trying to add my own class file into ASP.NET MVC project, so it could
be referenced by my controller. But Visual studio 2010 always complain about "The type or name 'Products' could not be found (are your missing a using directive or assembly reference?)

I am not sure where to put my class file and tried add the class to Models or Controllers directory, and it wouldn't work either. My the class is under the right namespace, and I did reference the Models namespace in my Controller. It could be something obvious, but I couldn't get it working:(

Comment: you're currently unable to create a new .cs file in project?

Comment: It is a .cs class file define an class I want deserialize from XML object. It there a App_Code folder or something I could put the class file not strictly a model?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure that the "Build Action" property of the file is set to "Compile" in Visual Studio.  Perhaps when you initially added the file, you added it to a location or added it as a file type that did not automatically set the build action properly.

Comment: Thank, can build now. Think I added it initially in app_code folder and think that is one of the magic folder for MVC but didn't work. And then start move it to Models and then Controllers. Now I put it in Controllers folder, don't know should I create a Utility folder of Helper folder for that class file. It is intend used by Controller to Deserialize XML Object.

Comment: +1, good point Jacob - if it's not set to compile, it won't compile :)

Answer (score 0):

The general rule of thumb is that business objects go it the Models folder you're correct. If it isn't working you don't have the project configured correctly. In the controller where you wanted to reference the Products object, did you add a reference to Models.Products?

Are there any other errors in listed? Sometimes multiple errors in a solution can combine to create something like this.

Comment: It sounds like your question is misleading. You are able to add the class, you just having a problem using it correct? You can right click and click add class?

Comment: it is more like an utility object only used by controller, where it a good place for it?

Comment: hi the title is indeed not really clear, my apologize. I was trying asking two questions: One is the reason why my new class file couldn't be found, and another is where should I put my new class file, did I put it in the wrong place.

Comment: Well, that is one of the reasons I still prefer Make file over VS's build system. Normally it will be helpful if you do it in the right way, but it will give me the illusion of things will works magically, and if it didn't work, I failed to realize that it is just a build system with conventions. In the end, I learned more about the IDE rather than how the build system working. Just my options...

Comment: Utility classes are business level so most people put them in the model folder.

Comment: I am creating another similar project and now I am feel it make more sense to put products.cs into models folder rather than make it Utility or Help folder. And I will have few more customers and invoices class as well.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the namespace of your class is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Based on a comment to a different answer, it appears you're trying to add a utility or helper class.  I suggest you put it in a Helpers folder under the root of the project.

So first add the Helpers folder under the root of the project.  You should have the following structure when done (there may be other folders as well):

```
[project]
  - Content
  - Helpers
  - Controllers
  - Views
```

Now, add a new class to the Helpers folder.  Call this class ProductsHelper (in the Add New Item dialog make sure to put ProductsHelper.cs, as it's asking for the *file* name).

Now have a look in the new ProductsHelper.cs file.  Copy the namespace found in said file, to be used in the controller.

Now, add a using directive at the top of your controller that looks like the following:

```
using [copied namespace];
```

Sometimes projects are set up to use default namespaces that don't match the project name, in which case the namespace in your newly-added class file might be different than what you thought you should add as the using directive.  If you're wondering what the default namespace for your project is, you can see it in the project's properties, on the Application tab, in the "Default namespace" textbox (you can change it here as well).

Comment: Just saw your comment about using it to deserialize XML objects - in that case I would call it XmlHelper, not ProductsHelper.  I'd also consider using extension methods so you can write `object.Serialize()` and `xml.Deserialize()`, instead of `XmlHelper.Serialize(object)` and `XmlHelper.Deserialize(xml)`.

Comment: thank you very much for your detailed information. I actually just tried to create a folder myself called Utilities under root, and possible because I skipped add new class for that folder inside VS2010 and opt to create a new namespace by myself and VS2010 again couldn't found that class during compiling. I think it make little bit more sense create Helper folder rather than Utilities folder in MVC and it is a fairly small project, so I probably need only on extra folder.

Comment: thanks for the tip about extension method. I didn't know it before, I did some reading and have to finish this project first and do a little more reading. Will try to put it on the next version :D

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem adding some utility class .cs files to my new MVC project.
I was working mostly on  VS 2010 Website projects which compile differently from
Web Application Projects ( WAP ) like the MVC 3 Project.

Just to clarify Jacob's answer, In the VS Solution Explorer: right click on the class .cs file and select the Property Dialog and then set the property: Build Action  to Compile.
This will force the code to be compiled when you Build the project.

HTH, LA Guy